# android Login to website

Tags: android

Hi everyone I am trying to login to the NJIT site using Httpost. For some reason I keep getting rejected even if I use the correct username and password. I am kind a new with this php but from what I searched the problem is the website is looking for a cookie. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance

```
    public void postLoginData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://cp4.njit.edu/cp/home/login");

    try {
        // Add user name and password
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        String username = uname.getText().toString();

        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass","password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uuid", "0xACA021"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
            result.loadData(str,"text/html", "UTF-8");
        }else
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
            result.loadData(str,"text/html", "UTF-8");
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste error from Logcat ?